Warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type] at fighting function
I'm trying to solve a CodeWars exercise in which I have to evaluate the winner between two fighters.
The function returns a std:string.
The issue I'm having in the page says:

"warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
runtime error: execution reached the end of a value-returning function without returning a value"

At the two initial if's.
However, when I compile on my IDE, there is no such warning.
Any clues about what can be causing the issue?
std::string declareWinner(Fighter* fighter1, Fighter* fighter2, std::string firstAttacker) {

    //initialize stats to 0
    int firstAttackerHealth{0}, secondAttackerHealth{0}, secondAttackerDamage{0}, firstAttackerDamage{0};
    std::string secondAttacker;

    //decide who is the first attacker and assign stats values
    if (fighter1->getName() == firstAttacker) {
        firstAttacker =fighter1->getName();
        firstAttackerHealth = fighter1->getHealth();
        firstAttackerDamage = fighter1->getDamagePerAttack();

        secondAttacker = fighter2->getName();
        secondAttackerHealth = fighter2->getHealth();
        secondAttackerDamage = fighter2->getDamagePerAttack();

    }
    else if(fighter2->getName() == firstAttacker) {
        firstAttacker = fighter2->getName();
        firstAttackerHealth = fighter2->getHealth();
        firstAttackerDamage = fighter2->getDamagePerAttack();

        secondAttacker = fighter1->getName();
        secondAttackerHealth = fighter1->getHealth();
        secondAttackerDamage = fighter1->getDamagePerAttack();
    }

    cout << firstAttacker << " vs " << secondAttacker << '\n';
    cout << firstAttacker << " has a total of " << firstAttackerHealth << " points of health   '\n";
    cout << secondAttacker << " has a total of " << secondAttackerHealth << " points of health '\n";
    cout << "Fight!'\n'";

    //start the combat only if both health values are above 0
    while (firstAttackerHealth > 0 && secondAttackerHealth > 0) {

        //check for attacker health, if greater than 0, then they can damage the opponent
        if (firstAttackerHealth > 0) {
            std::cout << firstAttacker << " punches for " << firstAttackerDamage << '\n';
            secondAttackerHealth-=firstAttackerDamage;
            std::cout << secondAttacker << "'s life is now " << secondAttackerHealth << '\n';
        }
        if (secondAttackerHealth > 0) {

            std::cout << secondAttacker << " punches for " << secondAttackerDamage << '\n';
            firstAttackerHealth -= secondAttackerDamage;
            std::cout << firstAttacker << "'s life is now " << firstAttackerHealth << '\n';
        }
            
        // check for the first attacker with health less than 0 and returns the 
        // other attacker
        if (firstAttackerHealth <= 0) {
            std::cout << firstAttacker << "' health is: " << firstAttackerHealth << " , "
                << firstAttacker << " has lost '\n'";
            return secondAttacker;
        }
        else if (secondAttackerHealth <= 0)
        {
            std::cout << secondAttacker << "' health is: " << secondAttackerHealth << " , "
                << secondAttacker << " has lost '\n'";
            return firstAttacker;
        }
    }
}


Put throw 0; at the end of the function, and it will squelch the warning.

Look at the code paths. At the bottom you end with an 'else if' and there's a return statement if that expression is true. If that expression is not true, you fall out the bottom and there's no return statement to fulfill the method interface, which calls for a string to be returned.

//start the combat only if both health values are above 0 What happens if that isn't true. What is returned in that case?

@Ramirojos By the way such an if statement like that   if (fighter1->getName() == firstAttacker) {
firstAttacker =fighter1->getName();//... does not make sense. The reason of the warning is a bad function logic design.

If there is any potential of the last while loop exiting (rather than either keep looping, or executing a return), that would justify the warning.   The more complexity of code in the loop, the harder it is for a compiler to test that, so possibility of false positive.   In any event, add a return statement after the loop -it will stop the warning (and prevent undefined behaviour if the loop ever does end).   And, optionally, do any other checks (or give warnings, or abort(), or whatever) that that point - if you believe the loop does not exit, such tests will catch any bugs.

The problem is that the compiler does not analyze the code deep enough, to understand the connection between your while-statement and the if-else-if at the bottom. An easy way to fix this is to change your while statement to
while (true) {

thus making it clear that the loop can only be exited with a break or return.
Another possiblity is to move the return statement outside of the loop:
    std::string rv;
    while (firstAttackerHealth > 0 && secondAttackerHealth > 0) {

        //check fot attacker health, if greater than 0, then they can damage the opponent
        if (firstAttackerHealth > 0) {
            std::cout << firstAttacker << " punches for " << firstAttackerDamage << '\n';
            secondAttackerHealth-=firstAttackerDamage;
            std::cout << secondAttacker << "'s life is now " << secondAttackerHealth << '\n';
        }
        if (secondAttackerHealth > 0) {

            std::cout << secondAttacker << " punches for " << secondAttackerDamage << '\n';
            firstAttackerHealth -= secondAttackerDamage;
            std::cout << firstAttacker << "'s life is now " << firstAttackerHealth << '\n';
        }
            
        // check for the first attacker with health less than 0 and returns the 
        // other attacker
        if (firstAttackerHealth <= 0) {
            std::cout << firstAttacker << "' health is: " << firstAttackerHealth << " , "
                << firstAttacker << " has lost '\n'";
            rv = secondAttacker;
            break;
        }
        else if (secondAttackerHealth <= 0)
        {
            std::cout << secondAttacker << "' health is: " << secondAttackerHealth << " , "
                << secondAttacker << " has lost '\n'";
            rv = firstAttacker;
            break;
        }
    }
    return rv;

The break-statements are not really necessary as the while condition will become false anyways, if some of this code is executed.

The second approach with break statetments is very bad.  You could place the last if-else statement outside the while loop.
